# DKIM and SPF for Different Server

Tags: email, spam, spf, dkim

My situation like the following:

1. Web server hosted in Google Cloud with domain name lets say: example.com
2. Mail server hosted in Linode (lets say in server name: server.myserver.com) using cPanel with Mail Only and use example.com domain name.

The goal is to separate web and mail server in different server.

**In Google DNS :**

1. I set A record for example.com to Google cloud IP
2. I set the MX record to mail.example.com
3. I set A record for mail.example.com to Linode IP
4. I set SPF and DKIM with TXT record that generated from cPanel (linode side)
5. I set PTR to server.myserver.com

> - **PTR** status is passed when I check from http://leafdns.com
> - **SPF** status passed from https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx
> - **DKIM** status passed from https://mxtoolbox.com/dkim.aspx

With all settings above I can get incoming email with no issue, but when try to send an email, all email trapped in SPAM folder.

What's wrong with the settings above? Please help and thanks before :)

**UPDATE**

> After checking email header and get spf and DKIM are pass (OK) but
>   still trapped in spam, so I end it up by using third party of email
>   service. In this case I use Amazon Simple Email Service. Thanks all
>   for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Investigate the full headers on the receiving end. They probably have some kind of report leadign to the logic why the message was marked as spam.

Comment: Many providers classify _every_ mail sent from a cPanel system as spam. In addition to the information in the linked post, you should strongly consider getting rid of cPanel and using a standard mail server.

Comment: Even if it's just a configuration error, it's way much easier to fix without cPanel fighting back.

Comment: After checking email header and get spf and DKIM is pass (OK) but still trapped in spam, so I end it up by using third party of email service. In this case I use Amazon Simple Email Service. Thanks all for your help, really appreciate it.